# Sum of overlapping days - multiple date ranges by distinct IDs

Tags: r

Relatively new to R coding, so forgive the naivety.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(123, 123, 123, 12345, 12345, 12345, 1357, 246810, 246810, 9876),
  SubID = c(321, 456, 967, 98, 765, 1938, 210, 878, 2, 33),
  Unit = c("King", "Double", "Suite", "King", "King", "Double", "Suite", "Double", "King", "Double"),
  Startdate = as.Date(c("2020-08-16", "2020-01-01", "2010-02-15", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2022-08-02", "2022-08-06", "2022-10-09", "2017-07-08", "2019-02-08")),
  Enddate = as.Date(c("2023-09-25", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-16", "2020-05-01", "2023-09-16", "2022-08-15", "2022-10-01", "2023-10-15", "2022-10-09", "2023-09-08"))
)
```

I am trying to get a sum of overlapping days for all guests in my dataframe. Example data frame above. Each guest could have multiple stays that overlap their other stays (SubId differentiates those stays).

I've worked out a code below, which generates the following data frame, but I'm stuck on validating if this is correct. At a quick glance it doesn't look correct, but my eyes may be deceiving me. Any help figuring out how to validate or a better code would be greatly appreciated!

Please note my actual data frame has roughly 3k rows, so it's looking at a large amount of time.

TIA!

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(lubridate)

    dfoverlapdays <- df %>%
      mutate(
        overlap_days = pmax(0, min(Enddate, max(Enddate, na.rm = TRUE)) - Startdate + 1))    
  
 # Calculate overlapping days
     total_days <- sum(dfoverlapdays$overlap_days) 
    
     cat("Sum of days", total_days, "\n")
```

#Results:

```
    >  cat("Sum of days", total_days, "\n")
    Sum of days 5331
```

```
 ##trying to validate that the overlap_days is correct and evaluating EACH row, not just rows       corresponding to the distinct ID. 

    > dfoverlapdays

       ID SubID   Unit  Startdate    Enddate overlap_days
1     123   321   King 2020-08-16 2023-09-25            0
2     123   456 Double 2020-01-01 2020-08-20          122
3     123   967  Suite 2010-02-15 2020-08-16         3729
4   12345    98   King 2020-05-01 2020-05-01            1
5   12345   765   King 2020-05-01 2023-09-16            1
6   12345  1938 Double 2022-08-02 2022-08-15            0
7    1357   210  Suite 2022-08-06 2022-10-01            0
8  246810   878 Double 2022-10-09 2023-10-15            0
9  246810     2   King 2017-07-08 2022-10-09         1029
10   9876    33 Double 2019-02-08 2023-09-08          449`
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me how ID and SubID are intended to be used so I ignored them. The result is an example that calculates a sequence of days from start to end for each row. This is then made into a data frame for all rows. If a day appears more than once in the combined data frame, it is an overlap. I used a simpler data set so I could check it manually. Using the original data yields a value of 2271 days.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# A simpler data frame that should yield an answer of 5
# The first and second rows overlap by 2
# The third and fourth overlap by 3 (2020 is a leap year)
simpler <- data.frame(
    ID = c(123, 123, 123, 12345),
    SubID = c(321, 456, 967, 98),
    Unit = c("King", "Double", "Suite", "King"),
    Startdate = as.Date(c("2020-08-16", "2020-08-17", "2020-02-15", "2020-02-28")),
    Enddate = as.Date(c("2020-08-18", "2020-08-20", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02"))
)
df <- simpler

# Make a sequence of numbered days from start to end
# Return this as a data frame
getdaylist <- function(start_date, end_date){
    start <- as.numeric(start_date)
    end <- as.numeric(end_date)
    dates <- seq(start, end)
    dates_df <- data.frame(dates)
    dates_df
}

# Make a list of data frames
datelists_df <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) getdaylist(df$Startdate[row], df$Enddate[row]))

# Bind the data frames together
# group them by the date and then count them
# Filter out any with a count of 1 and
# determine the length of the resulting
# data frame
overlapping_days <- 
    bind_rows(datelists_df) %>% 
    group_by(dates) %>%
    count() %>% 
    filter(n > 1) %>%
    nrow()

overlapping_days
#[1] 5
```